# Showing posts from 4 categories along with all latest posts

Tags: wp-query, query

Currently in my theme i am running the default **query** that pulls all **recent posts/latest entries/latest published posts** . But i am looking for something more complex like i am gonna **setup** two sections . One is for all the **latest entries** and the other one is for the four **sub-sections which will show posts from 4 selected categories** but the posts of those selected categories wont be showed in the latest entries i mean the first query which was pulling all posts will **exclude** the posts of 4 **selected categories** . cause there will be duplication  ..

but i don't know the exact query/wp-query code for this type of setting . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first do the 4 queries for selected categories and while looping through them remember the IDs. Save them in an array. Then when pulling latest posts just add the `post__not_in` parameter with all the IDs you want to exclude.

You need 4 queries that look somewhat like this:

```
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => 'category1'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        //do something
        $excludeIDs[] = the_ID();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

and then one something like this:

```
    $args = array(
        'post__not_in' => $excludeIDs
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        //do something else
        $excludeIDs[] = the_ID();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

That should get you started. If you need any other help, just ask.

Comment: thanks for the answer . but can you demonstrate an example code? i am not a query pro and i only know some basic things .

Comment: What does your code look like now? some of this varies from theme to theme.

Comment: @SadiMahmud ok, I've updated my answer with code examples